# How to access Selenium's logs with JavaScript Webdriver to view network requests

Tags: javascript, logging, selenium-webdriver, network-traffic

I'm trying to open a website and view all the network requests the page sends. I can see in the documentation ([here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/logging.html)) this code snippet:

```
var prefs = new logging.Preferences();
 prefs.setLevel(logging.Type.BROWSER, logging.Level.DEBUG);

 var caps = Capabilities.chrome();
 caps.setLoggingPrefs(prefs);
 // ...
```

but I do not get where I'm supposed to get logging and capabilities from and cannot find any examples of this in Javascript.

This is what I have so far:

```
var chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

async function LibraryAppTest() {
    let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome'}).build();

    await driver.get('http://library-app.firebaseapp.com');
    await driver.findElement(By.css('input'));
    await driver.findElement(By.css('.btn-lg')).getText().then(function(text){
        console.log("Button Text: " + text);
    });
    await driver.quit();
}

LibraryAppTest()
.then(_ => console.log('SUCCESS!'), e => console.error('FAILURE: ' + e));
```

This works as is, I just can't understand how I'm supposed to set up the logging preferences and use them to see the network calls the page makes.

Comment: I haven't done a lot with this but from what I remember, this is purely for the logging that happens in the dev console and doesn't have anything to do with the network traffic.

Comment: You might look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/beDuY1DGZRA)

Answer (score 1):

You define the preferences as shown

```
var prefs = new logging.Preferences();
prefs.setLevel(logging.Type.BROWSER, logging.Level.DEBUG);
```

Then you set the preferences in the capabilities

```
const capabilities = {
    "browserName": "Chrome",
    "goog:loggingPrefs": prefs
    }
```

Finally you build the driver:

```
driver = await new Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).forBrowser('chrome').build();
```